# When is the stationary distribution of a Markov chain the reciprocal of return times?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

What conditions need to hold for each element of the stationary distribution to be the reciprocal of the expected return time to that state? If a Markov chain has a stationary distribution, is it always the case that the elements of stationary distribution are the reciprocals of the return times?

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear in that by using a definite article for "stationary distribution" in the title and in the first sentence, you seem to already be implying that the chain has exactly one stationary distribution. That leads to a slightly different question than you pose in the second sentence, where you only assume that the chain has "a" stationary distribution. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I'm interested in the answers to both questions but I would guess that the answer is no if the stationary distribution is not unique (because it doesn't make sense for the return times to not be unique)?